# Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

In an HTML table, the `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` can be set like this:

```html
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
```

How can the same be accomplished using CSS?

Comment: Just a general suggestion, check to see if your style.css does a "reset" on your tables before trying these solutions. Example: If you don't have tables set to `width:auto` then `border-collapse` might not work as expected.

Comment: Use border-spacing on table and padding on td.

Comment: "Oh, dang, back in the olden days I did this with `cellpadding` and `cellspacing`... what is that in CSS again?" –me, pretty much every time I need to do this.

Answer (score 3884, accepted):

**Basics**

For controlling "cellpadding" in CSS, you can simply use `padding` on table cells. E.g. for 10px of "cellpadding":

```css
td, th { /* table cells */
    padding: 10px;
}
```

For "cellspacing", you can apply the `border-spacing` CSS property to your table. E.g. for 10px of "cellspacing":

```css
table { 
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

This property will even allow separate horizontal and vertical spacing, something you couldn't do with old-school "cellspacing".

**Issues in IE ≤  7**

This will work in almost all popular browsers except for Internet Explorer up through Internet Explorer 7, where you're almost out of luck. I say "almost" because these browsers still support the `border-collapse` property, which merges the borders of adjoining table cells. If you're trying to eliminate cellspacing (that is, `cellspacing="0"`) then `border-collapse:collapse` should have the same effect: no space between table cells. This support is buggy, though, as it does not override an existing `cellspacing` HTML attribute on the table element.

In short: for non-Internet Explorer 5-7 browsers, `border-spacing` handles you. For Internet Explorer, if your situation is just right (you want 0 cellspacing and your table doesn't have it defined already), you can use `border-collapse:collapse`.

```css
table { 
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Note: For a great overview of CSS properties that one can apply to tables and for which browsers, see this [fantastic Quirksmode page](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html).

Comment: cellpadding="0" can still make a difference in Chrome 13.0.782.215, even if border-collapse:collapse and border-spacing are applied to the table.

Comment: That certainly makes sense due to css specificity, so you may need to apply the styles to a css id for maximum specificity.  Not sure that'll override attribute values in all cases, but it's the place to start checking.

Comment: @LeeWhitney you need to set padding: 0 on your table cells.

Comment: It's little bit off topic, but cellpadding and cellspacing attributes are removed in HTML5, so CSS is the only way to go now.

Comment: Hi, all. I've updated the answer for clarity, including a section on cellpadding, which I'd thought was obvious (just use "padding"). Hope it's more useful now.

Comment: This is NOT a good answer.  It says add this CSS, which will apply it to all of the tables and cells on the page.  What if you have multiple tables on a page, and want different cellpaddings or cellspacing for each of them?

Comment: True, @vapcguy, in any of the infinitely variable other situations you may be styling a table in, you will need to define more specific selectors. The above are marked as examples.

Comment: Padding is not the same by default. For example if your table cell has a background color, then the padding will also include that background. Not exactly "cell spacing". That's why it's called "padding".
Naturally margin should work on table cells, but it doesn't, and i'm not the one who broke it.

Comment: Note that `border-collapse:collapse` is NOT equivalent to `cellspacing="0"`. The former results in a single line between cells, while the latter results in two lines between cells.

Comment: Don't you want `td, th`  with the padding?

Answer (score 1026):

### Default

The default behavior of the browser is equivalent to:

```css
table  {border-collapse: collapse;}
td, th {padding: 0px;}
```

[image]

### Cellpadding

Sets the amount of space between the contents of the cell and the cell wall

```css
table  {border-collapse: collapse;}
td, th {padding: 6px;}
```

[image]

### Cellspacing

Controls the space between table cells

table  {border-spacing: 2px;}
td, th {padding: 0px;}

[image]

### Both

```css
table  {border-spacing: 2px;}
td, th {padding: 6px;}
```

[image]

### Both (special)

```css
table  {border-spacing: 8px 2px;}
td, th {padding: 6px;}
```

[image]

> **Note:** If there is `border-spacing` set, it indicates `border-collapse` property of the table is `separate`.

[Try it yourself!](http://jsfiddle.net/H4emK/3303/)

[Here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_29.html) you can find the old HTML way of achieving this.

Comment: How is the spacing around the table disappearing? When I set "border-spacing: 8px 12px, it adds the spacing not just between, but between the table border and the outside cells! But that is not depicted in the images here; they are flush left.

Comment: @2astalavista And unfortunately if someone wants the effect of the exterior spacing deleted, it won't work this way with these CSS attributes.

Comment: @Kaz You might need use negative margin to hide that annoying part.

Comment: The default padding on TD is typically 1px, not 0

Comment: Beware: `border-spacing:horizontal vertical;` whereas, for example, `padding:vertical horizontal;`.

Answer (score 370):

```css
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse; /* 'cellspacing' equivalent */
}

table td, table th
{
    padding: 0; /* 'cellpadding' equivalent */
}
```

Comment: That's `cellspacing=0` equivalent. The equivalent for `cellspacing=1` is completely different. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 124):

Setting margins on table cells doesn't really have any effect as far as I know. The true CSS equivalent for `cellspacing` is `border-spacing` - but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

You can use `border-collapse: collapse` to reliably set cell spacing to 0 as mentioned, but for any other value I think the only cross-browser way is to keep using the `cellspacing` attribute.

Comment: In today's age that reality is suckage to the Nth degree.

Comment: This is almost correct, but `border-collapse` only works in IE 5-7 if the table doesn't already have a `cellspacing` attribute defined. I've written a comprehensive answer that merges all the correct parts of the other answers on this page in case that's helpful.

Answer (score 111):

This hack works for Internet Explorer 6 and later, [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), Firefox, and [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29):

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px; /* cellspacing */
    *border-collapse: expression('separate', cellSpacing = '10px');
}

table td, table th {
    padding: 10px; /* cellpadding */
}
```

The `*` declaration is for Internet Explorer 6 and 7, and other browsers will properly ignore it.

`expression('separate', cellSpacing = '10px')` returns `'separate'`, but both statements are run, as in JavaScript you can pass more arguments than expected and all of them will be evaluated.

Answer (score 74):

For those who want a non-zero cellspacing value, the following CSS worked for me, but I'm only able to test it in Firefox.

See the [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html) link [posted elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css/3209434#3209434) for compatibility details. It seems it may not work with older Internet Explorer versions.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 57):

The simple solution to this problem is:

```css
table
{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
table td
{
    padding: 8px 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 55):

Also, if you want `cellspacing="0"`, don't forget to add `border-collapse: collapse` in your `table`'s stylesheet.

Answer (score 47):

Wrap the contents of the cell with a div and you can do anything you want, but you have to wrap every cell in a column to get a uniform effect. For example, to just get wider left & right margins:

So the CSS will be,

```css
div.cellwidener {
  margin: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
}
td.tight {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="tight">
      <div class="cellwidener">My content</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Yes, it's a hassle. Yes, it works with Internet Explorer. In fact, I've only tested this with Internet Explorer, because that's all we're allowed to use at work.

Answer (score 26):

This style is for **full reset for tables** - **cellpadding**, **cellspacing** and **borders**.

I had this style in my reset.css file:

```
table{
    border:0;          /* Replace border */
    border-spacing: 0px; /* Replace cellspacing */
    border-collapse: collapse; /* Patch for Internet Explorer 6 and Internet Explorer 7 */
}
table td{
    padding: 0px; /* Replace cellpadding */
}
```

Answer (score 22):

TBH. For all the fannying around with CSS you might as well just use `cellpadding="0"` `cellspacing="0"` since they are not deprecated...

Anyone else suggesting margins on `<td>`'s obviously has not tried this.

Comment: They are actually deprecated in html5.

Answer (score 19):

**Simply use CSS padding rules with table data:**

```
td { 
    padding: 20px;
}
```

And for border spacing:

```
table { 
    border-spacing: 1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

***However, it can create problems in older version of browsers like Internet Explorer because of the diff implementation of the box model.***

Answer (score 17):

From what I understand from the W3C classifications is that `<table>`s are meant for displaying data 'only'.

Based on that I found it a lot easier to create a `<div>` with the backgrounds and all that and have a table with data floating over it using `position: absolute;` and `background: transparent;`...

It works on Chrome, Internet Explorer (6 and later) and Mozilla Firefox (2 and later).

Margins are used (or meant anyways) to create a spacer between container elements, like `<table>`, `<div>` and `<form>`, not `<tr>`, `<td>`, `<span>` or `<input>`. Using it for anything other than container elements will keep you busy adjusting your website for future browser updates.

Answer (score 15):

CSS:

```
selector{
    padding:0 0 10px 0; // Top left bottom right 
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can easily set padding inside the table cells using the CSS padding property. It is a valid way to produce the same effect as the table's cellpadding attribute.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 10px;
  /* Apply cell padding */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Set Cellpadding in CSS</title>

</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Row</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Clark</td>
        <td>Kent</td>
        <td>clarkkent@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Parker</td>
        <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Rambo</td>
        <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Similarly, you can use the CSS border-spacing property to apply the spacing between adjacent table cell borders like the cellspacing attribute. However, in order to work border-spacing the value of border-collapse property muse be separate, which is default.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  /* Apply cell spacing */
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px;
  /* Apply cell padding */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Set Cellspacing in CSS</title>

</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Row</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Clark</td>
        <td>Kent</td>
        <td>clarkkent@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Parker</td>
        <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Rambo</td>
        <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
table td, table th {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Or try this:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I used `!important` after the border-collapse like

```css
border-collapse: collapse !important;
```

and it works for me in IE7. It seems to override the cellspacing attribute.

Comment: `!important` would only be needed to override *other CSS settings* in a complex situation (and even then mostly a wrong approach).

Answer (score 9):

Say that we want to assign a 10px "cellpadding" and a 15px "cellspacing" to our table, in a HTML5-compliant way. I will show here two methods giving really similar outputs.

Two different sets of CSS properties apply to the same HTML markup for the table, but with opposite concepts:

- the first one uses the default value for `border-collapse` (`separate`) and uses `border-spacing` to provide the cellspacing,
- the second one switches `border-collapse` to `collapse` and uses the `border` property as the cellspacing.

In both cases, the cellpadding is achieved by assigning `padding:10px` to the `td`s and, in both cases, the `background-color` assigned to them is only for the sake of a clearer demo.

**First method:**

```css
table{border-spacing:15px}
td{background-color:#00eb55;padding:10px;border:0}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Header 1</td><td>Header 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Second method:**

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse}
td{background-color:#00eb55;padding:10px;border:15px solid #fff}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Header 1</td><td>Header 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
td {
    padding: npx; /* For cellpadding */
    margin: npx; /* For cellspacing */
    border-collapse: collapse; /* For showing borders in a better shape. */
}
```

If `margin` didn't work, try to set `display` of `tr` to `block` and then margin will work.