# CSS table cellpadding and cellspacing?

Tags: html, css

> #### Possible Duplicate:
>
> [How to set cellpadding & cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-cellspacing-in-css)

i have a little problem, i don't know how i can make my CSS style to remove cellpadding and cellspacing.

i hobe i can be helpet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
table {  
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer of `border-collapse:collapse;` is not the right way to get rid of `cellspacing`.  It works for simple `solid` border styles, but it is easily seen to be wrong if `td{border}` is set to something complicated, like `inset` or `outset`.  The right answer is `border-spacing:0;`