# Table padding not working

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, css-tables

I have a table that sits within a parent div full of body text and other content. I have the following CSS which does not seem to work:

```
table {width:100%; padding: 0 50px 0 50px;}
```

When I use margins instead of padding, it works—however, with width:100%, using margins scoots the whole thing out of the parent div. I guess I could reduce the width or specify an exact pixel amount, but the rest of the site scales with screen size and I'd like this to work like that, too.

Comment: You could set the margin *and* width of the table to percentages.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750670/how-do-you-specify-table-padding-in-css-table-not-cell-padding

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are some special properties related to tables. The one you are looking for is `border-spacing`.

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 50px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/fPuQ6/

**UPDATE:** After playing around with my own fiddle I must admit, that I was wrong by telling that "a table doesn't have a padding". The padding on the table is working fine – at least when viewed in Chrome and Opera (12). The following snippet should do want you want too:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
}
```

See the updated version of the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/fPuQ6/3/

Nonetheless I'm still wondering why the padding isn't added to the width as for an element with `display: block;`.

See also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Tables

Comment: `border-collapse: seperate` has so many unintended and bad side effects that any answer telling people to switch to using it is probably not an answer most people should be using

Comment: @JohnMiller Can you note which side-effects or can you please add a link to some sort of documentation on those?

Answer (score 12):

This is the reason why;

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing), to use padding in tables, you need to have `border-collapse: separate;` so as to allow for the use of `border-spacing` because `border-spacing` is a factor in the calculation of distance between the outer table edge and the edge of the outer cells (see quotes from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) below). After that you can now assign `padding` a value. You can also set `border-spacing: 0px;` to cancel out the addition of `border-spacing` to the padding.

> The border-spacing CSS property sets the distance between the borders of adjacent  cells. This property applies only when border-collapse is separate.
>
> The border-spacing value is also used along the outside edge of the table, where the distance between the table's border and the cells in the first/last column or row is the sum of the relevant (horizontal or vertical) border-spacing and the relevant (top, right, bottom, or left) padding on the table.

Answer (score 6):

The prior answer shows that css can set border-[direction] for ea direction separately. But a much simpler css-only solution that replicates the old-style `table cellpadding="7" border="1"` can be the following.  In CSS:

```
table { 
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  padding: 7px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

Shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5NW5/77

Answer (score 3):

You can add the cell padding in the table definition OR if you want to use CSS then use can try this:

If using CSS:

```
<style type="text\css">
.table {
        width: 100%;        
        border-top:1px solid red;
        border-right:1px solid red;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
.table td {
    padding: 7px;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    border-left:1px solid red;
}
</style>

<table class="table">
    <tr><td>Cell1a</td><td>Cell1b</td><td>Cell1c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell2a</td><td>Cell2b</td><td>Cell2c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell3a</td><td>Cell3b</td><td>Cell3c</td></tr>
</table>
```

If using inline:

```
<table cellpadding="9" cellspacing="5" style="border-collapse:collapse;" border="1">
    <tr><td>Cell1a</td><td>Cell1b</td><td>Cell1c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell2a</td><td>Cell2b</td><td>Cell2c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell3a</td><td>Cell3b</td><td>Cell3c</td></tr>
</table>
```

You can see this in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/b5NW5/1/

Hope it helps