# Why should I keep the cellspacing attribute in the markup?

Tags: html, css

I was looking for some resources about the use of CSS instead of tables and reached [this presentation](http://stopdesign.com/present/2004/ddw-seattle/tables/) by Douglas Bowman that seems to be a 'classic'. I dug into it and found this sentence about the tables in the [slide 6](http://stopdesign.com/present/2004/ddw-seattle/tables/?no=6) that is very intriguing:

> **Keep the `cellspacing` attribute in the markup.**

It's curious that in Eric Meyer's reset CSS is:

```
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

These makes me think having cellspacing in the mark up is really a best practice I didn't know. In my opinion the cellspacing is more about the presentation than about the semantics of the info. I've been thinking for a while but haven't been able to figure out why should I keep it in the HTML?

Comment: Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-cellspacing-in-css/339997#339997?

Comment: @Crescent Fresh - So just browser compatibility?

Comment: @victor: Looks to be, yes. IE7 and lower don't support it: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html  But I'm far from an expert on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `border-collapse: collapse` on all browsers. But other values for `border-collapse` and the `border-spacing` property are not supported before IE8.

Personally, I've never found a reason to use anything other than `border-collapse: collapse` - separated borders on tables usually look pretty awful.

Comment: +1: the way to go. Just get rid of `cellspacing=0` and use `table { border-collapse: collapse; }` instead.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of border-collapse. I'm just wondering why would somebody use cellspacing markup attribute

Comment: Well I guess what he means is that if you *want* cellspacing, the only reliable way to do it (back then, anyway) is to use the attribute, not CSS.