# Add space between cells (td) using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a table with space between cell as the background colour of the cell is white and the background color of the table is blue, you can easily see that padding and margin are not working (I am applying it to the `td`), it will only add space inside of the cell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You want `border-spacing`:

```
<table style="border-spacing: 10px;">
```

Or in a CSS block somewhere:

```
table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

See [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html#borderspacing) on `border-spacing`. Be aware that `border-spacing` does not work on IE7 and below.

Comment: in IE7 and below, you can use the cellspacing attribute in the table tag. You can supply both to get it working in IE also. Other browsers will prioritize the style.

Answer (score 43):

```
table { 
  border-spacing: 10px; 
}
```

This worked for me once I removed

```
border-collapse: separate;
```

from my table tag.

Comment: separate instead of seperate, but it helped me :-)

Comment: Yeah didn't know you had to change the 'border-collapse' too. This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 34):

Mine is:

```
border-spacing: 10px;
border-collapse: separate;
```

Comment: i need to add the boder-collapse css property for the margin to take affect. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` attributes for `table` tag or `border-spacing` css property.

Answer (score 4):

cellspacing (distance between cells) parameter of the TABLE tag is precisely what you want. The disadvantage is it's one value, used both for x and y, you can't choose different spacing or padding vertically/horizontally. There is a CSS property too, but it's not widely supported.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose `cellspcing` / `cellpadding` / `border-spacing` property did not worked, you can use the code as follow.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <table width="100%" cellspacing="2px" style="border-spacing: 10px;">
    <tr>                        
      <td width="47%">
        <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-info" id="submit" name="Submit" />
      </td>
      <td width="5%"></td>
      <td width="47%">
        <input type="reset" class="form-control btn btn-info" id="reset" name="Reset" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I've tried and got succeed while seperate the button by using table-width and make an empty td as 2 or 1% it doesn't return more different.

Answer (score 0):

If you want separate values for sides and top-bottom.

```
<table style="border-spacing: 5px 10px;">
```