# Insert a tab or spaces in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to html and I got this piece of code:

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>View1</title>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>  
        <table>    
            @foreach (var item in Model.Data)
            { 
                <tr>
                    <td><a href=@Model.DataUrl[item.Key]>@item.Key</a></td>
                    <td>@item.Value</td>
                </tr>                        
            }
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to add a tab or spaces between: `<td><a href=@Model.DataUrl[item.Key]>@item.Key</a></td>` and `<td>@item.Value</td>` how do I do that?

I guess adding css is the best way but I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: In HTML `&nbsp;` = space, `&#09;` = tab.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a gap between the `td`s?  You probably want to either use margin or padding, both css properties

Comment: Is there a way to add the css propery without creating a new .css file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add padding to your `td` with CSS:

```css
td {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Hello</a></td>
    <td>Goodbye</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Hola</a></td>
    <td>Adios</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or give them a fixed width:

```css
td {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Hello</a></td>
    <td>Goodbye</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Hola</a></td>
    <td>Adios</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way to add the css propery without creating a new .css file?

Comment: @PresidentCamacho Yes, as I alread said, you can just drop those `<style>` elements into the `<head>` of your .cshtml file to try them out.

Comment: I added the <style> in the <body> enclosure and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Of course it would be bad practice to add styling to all TDs like this. It is better to add classes instead and style those.

Answer (score 8):

```
`&nbsp;` is a space
`&#09;` is a tab
```

Just insert them where you want

For the CSS, you should use the padding property, there are plenty of tutorials on the web, and samples

Comment: Tab or space between two table columns?

Comment: Just try it! If you fail, put your blank space into the column...

Comment: I tries adding &#09; like this: <td>&#09;@item.Value</td> but that doesn't do anything. adding without ; makes @item.Value a string and not a variable.

Comment: You must put it into the column

Comment: how do I add it into a column?

Answer (score 3):

```
<table style="border-spacing: 10px;">
```

Or in a CSS block somewhere:

```
table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

Source : [Add space between cells (td) using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070817/add-space-between-cells-td-using-css)

Answer (score 2):

You mean visual whitespace?

In that case, check [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp) for:

- How to add styles for a table
- The paragraph Table Padding specifically.

Basic CSS isn't that hard.