# Spacing between columns in a table

Tags: css, html-table, spacing

I have a big problem with the spacing of columns in a table.
Here's what I'd like to get, spacing only between `<td>`:

[image]

Not working with `margin`, `padding`  or `border`:

```css
td {
  padding-left: 7.5px;
  padding-right: 7.5px;
}

td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
```

[image]

Not working with `border-spacing`:

[image]

And if use `first-child` and `last-child`, same problem as previous image.

Solution I found, but really dirty:

```css
.spacer {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<td></td>
<div id="spacer"></div>
<td></td>
<div id="spacer"></div>
<td></td>
<div id="spacer"></div>
<td></td>
```

Comment: You want to remove or add that `15px` spacing?

Comment: how about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070817/add-space-between-cells-td-using-css

Comment: Can't you undo the unwanted spacing created by `border-spacing` with `margin: -15px` for the `table`?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn unfortunately not!

Comment: @Swellar I want to get 15px spacing only between td. Example : <td><space><td><space><td>
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `border-spacing: 15px 0px` to generate only horizontal spacing;
2. To not display only left and right spacing, you can wrap the table in a div, and set `margin: 0px -15px` to table. Then, set `overflow: hidden;` to div how hide extra left and right spacing.

```css
td {
  padding-left: 7.5px;
  padding-right: 7.5px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 25%;
}

td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

table {
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 15px 0px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0px -15px;
}

.table-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> 1) You must use Standard structure for table when you want work with css on it.

**change :**

```
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
```

**To:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>   
</table>
```

> 2) If want space between `TDs` add `border-spacing:30px 0px;` to table.

```css
td {
  padding-left: 7.5px;
  padding-right: 7.5px;
  background-color: orange;
}

td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

table {
    border-spacing:30px 0px;
  }
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
 <td>TD1</td>
 <td>TD2</td>
 <td>TD3</td>
 <td>TD4</td>
   </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Good point about standard structure but unfortunately this is not an answer to the question. Please read again and edit your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but with this way we get problem i show in image n°2 http://i.imgur.com/OVtjnu1.png

Answer (score 1):

Use `<div>` and `margin` instead.

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cell {
  float: left; /* make the divs sit next to each other like cells */
  background: red;
  width: calc(25% - 12px); /* 4 cells so 25% but minus 12 because we have 3 x 15px margins divided by 4 cells which is 11.25 but decimals can cause issues in some browsers */
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.cell:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you have well understand my question, your reply seem to work ! But with this way, we need to know how many exactly have cells (for 4 cells : calc(25% - 12px)), possible to do it auto ? Thanks anyway

Comment: @PierreArkona yes, it is a messy solution. You could set different classes for different tables e.g. `<div class="table 4cols">` and declare the different widths in the css e.g. `.4cols .cell { width: calc(25% - 12px); }`

Comment: Thanks, i think i will couple your way with javascript to get it 100% auto !

Answer (score -2):

Try to use `cellspacing` attribute.

```html
<table cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but with this way, have unwanted margin arround the td's https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOv3P.png