# remove space between two td elements in a table

Tags: html, css

I have a table with one tr & 2 tds. The 2 td's have tables. There is space between the 2 inner tables, which I don't want. Can someone suggest me how to remove this spacing.
Here is my mark up:

```
 <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-width: 0; padding: 0; border-width: 0;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" style="border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid grey; width: 100%; border-collapse: initial;" id="Table1">
                <tr>
                    <td>Subscriber Name: </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="Text1" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Subscriber Id: </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="Text2" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="button" id="Button1" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" style="border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid grey; width: 100%; border-collapse: initial;" id="Table2">
                <tr>
                    <td>Admin Name: </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="Text3" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Admin Id:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="Text4" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="button" id="Button2" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the padding of the cells themselves to 0.  They do not inherit the padding of the table element.

```
<table style="border-spacing: 0; border-width: 0; padding: 0; border-width: 0;">
<tr>
    <td style="padding-right: 0px;">
        <table width="100%" style="border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid grey; width: 100%; border-collapse: initial;" id="Table1">
            <tr>
                <td>Subscriber Name: </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="Text1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Subscriber Id: </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="Text2" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <input type="button" id="Button1" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-left: 0px;">
        <table width="100%" style="border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid grey; width: 100%; border-collapse: initial;" id="Table2">
            <tr>
                <td>Admin Name: </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="Text3" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Admin Id:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="Text4" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <input type="button" id="Button2" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you added style="padding-left: 0px;" to td elements of outer table, I thought I don't need to do it, as I have padding: 0; in the table itself. However, seeing your answer, I tried it & it worked out.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can simple use:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" style="border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid grey; width: 100%; border-collapse: initial;" id="Table1">
                <tr>
                    <td>Subscriber Name: </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="Text1" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Subscriber Id: </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="Text2" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="button" id="Button1" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" style="border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid grey; width: 100%; border-collapse: initial;" id="Table2">
                <tr>
                    <td>Admin Name: </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="Text3" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Admin Id:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="Text4" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="button" id="Button2" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: By using border-collapse I am loosing the rounded borders, I don't know why.
Infact, My table is in a div inside which border-collapse is made for all tables, so I am overriding it with border-collapse:initial to get rounded border

Answer (score 4):

include `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` in the `table` tag

**HTML**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hx6pmrcz/)

Comment: `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` are obsolete in html5.

Comment: cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" in table tag are absolete, however I am doing the same with 

style="border-spacing: 0; border-width: 0; padding: 0; border-width: 0;"

Comment: @Alex check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414773/is-it-ok-to-use-cellpadding-2-cellspacing-2-in-table, even that is obsolete, we can use..

Comment: @RasmitaDash, else we can update "table {border-collapse: collapse;} td {padding: 0px;}"

Comment: I know we can use it but is obsolete :) Btw i didn't downvote.

Comment: not an issue, we can use "table {border-collapse: collapse;} td {padding: 0px;}"