# CellPadding on VerticalPanel (GWT)

Tags: html, gwt

I am trying to set a cellpadding value for my vertical panel. There is an API to set cellspacing (CellPanel.setSpacing()) but none for setting the cellpadding.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use css to do this.  Refer to the [dev guide](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html).
Basically you want to set a style name on the panel using one of the setStyle* methods.
Once you do this you use css to apply the styles for the particular name.

Comment: cellpadding is a Element attribute not a style attribute.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-cellspacing-in-css has examples of setting things like th, td { padding: 0 } to accomplish this once you've applied a style as Carnell suggested.

Answer (score 4):

I did it like this:

```
myVerticalPanel.getElement().setAttribute("cellpadding", "5");
```

Carnell's answer does not work for IE7 and earlier versions.

Comment: please change the spelling. setAttribute("cellpadding", "5");