# How to define cellspacing in CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a table, where cellspacing is set to 0.
Currently I have the following HTML which works correctly. But I want to put the cellspacing to the CSS, but can't find the correct style for it.

```
<table class="overviewGrid" id="OrderTable" cellspacing="0px">
</table>
```

Can anybody help me?
Thx in advance

Comment: This is a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-cellspacing-in-css/3209434#3209434

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The CSS equivalent of `<table>`'s `cellspacing` attribute is `border-spacing`. However, Māris Kiseļovs' answer (`border-collapse`) is the one you should use to remove the cell spacing.

Answer (score 0):

```
table {border-spacing: 8px 2px;}
td    {padding: 6px;}
```