# Table's Getting 1px of Unwanted Padding

Tags: html, css, html-table, margin, padding

For some reason I'm getting a 1px padding or border on a table. I can't figure out how to get rid of it. I've tried adding `display:block;margin:0;padding:0;` to the images, but that doesn't solve it. I've also tried `<table border="0">` and `border:none;` in the CSS. For the life of me I can't figure this out.

The reason it's a problem is because I'm trying to get images to line up with the edges on both sides of a tr, to give it rounded borders, since CSS3 border-radius doesn't work on TR's. I've added `table, table * {border:1px solid red;}` to the CSS, and from that, it definitely looks like a padding or margin issue.

The issue is in this image:

[image]

on the left and right sides, you can see there's some kind of padding or something between the images and the edge of the table. The red borders are there just to see this.

Here's my CSS:

```
table a {
    color: #f7941E;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* css3 */
    transition: color .25s;
    -khtml-transition: color .25s;
    -moz-transition: color .25s;
    -o-transition: color .25s;
    -webkit-transition: color .25s;
}

    table a:hover {
        color: #f8ae57;
    }

table {
    width: 610px;
}

    table tr {
        height: 33px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

        table td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

    table tr.head {
        color: #58585a;
        font-family: Rockwell, serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }

    table tr.even {
        background: #EEE;
        height: 33px;
    }

        table tr td img {
            padding: 0 15px 0 13px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

            table tr td a img {
                opacity: .6;                
                /* css3 */
                transition: opacity .25s;
                -khtml-transition: opacity .25s;
                -moz-transition: opacity .25s;
                -o-transition: opacity .25s;
                -webkit-transition: opacity .25s;
            }

                table tr td a img:hover {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
```

And the HTML:

```
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/tr-left.png" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;">
        <td><img src="images/some-icon.png" /> <a href="#">Some Content</a></td>
        <td><img src="images/tr-right.png" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;">
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a table-less layout? Table layouts are frowned upon (begin argument here).

Comment: Why not just reset margin/padding in CSS for tables?

Comment: No one arguments that anymore Blender.

Comment: You need to close the first `<td>` and your `<tr>`

Comment: @Blender, I know that, but this is actually a situation in which tables are useful. The way there structured makes for a way to list items in a CMS, in my opinion. Tables in most situations are extremely annoying.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try: `<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">`

Comment: Ahh! Thank you very much! I thought my CSS reset took care of that, but that fixed it right up!

Comment: This option is deprecated in HTML5, but fortunately you can do the same thing in CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css

Answer (score 12):

This seemed to fix things for me.

**CSS:**

```
table {
    width: 610px;
    border-spacing:0; /* Add this here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was some weird behavior, and I had tried all the tricks in the book, but that **padding** was stubborn. Finally I found out, that the **`line-height`** attribute set for the **`body`** element, was creating the effect of `padding-top`. After overriding which, with a localized rule, of

`line-height: normal;`

...the problem got solved.