# alternative to using cellpadding in outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Since cellpadding causes errors in outlook emails. What are the other logical workarounds for it?

I do not want to use a `<div>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about some inline css; `style="cell-padding:10px;"`?

There's an answer to another StackOverflow question that does in some detail about this at [Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-cellspacing-in-css/3209434#3209434).

Comment: `cell-padding`? that's not even a valid property