# Spaces between table rows with borders in CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablesorter

I'm trying to display a table where each table row has a rounded border. I'm looking to add spaces between these borders and not within the row itself.  Originally, I had an additional row `<tr class='spacer'>` in between each row to space them out, but have since added sorter functionality to my table using a jQuery plugin, Tablesorter.

When I try to sort my table, these spacers sort to the bottom or top, removing the spacing between each row.

What I'm looking for is a way to space between each of these rows and still allow the table to be sortable.

//HTML Follows//

```
<html>
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="table.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter(); 
}); 
</script>

</head>

<body>

<table class="tablesorter" cellspacing=0>
<thead> 
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class='roundleft'>Keanan</td>
    <td class='spacer'>01/11/11 6:52 AM</td>
    <td class='roundright'>$20.95</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class='roundleft'>Conor</td>
    <td class='spacer'>01/11/11 4:52 PM</td>
    <td class='roundright'>$200.00</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class='roundleft'>Ryan</td>
    <td class='spacer'>01/11/11 12:52 PM</td>
    <td class='roundright'>$1.00</td>
</tr>

</tbody>    
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

//CSS follows//

```
body { 
  text-align:center
  margin:50px 0px; 
  padding:0px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}

#content {
  font-weight:normal;
  background: #009900;
  width:700px;
  margin:0px auto;
  color:white;
  border:2px solid  #000000;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

table{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: black;
  border: 3px black solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #009900;
}

th{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #009900;
}

tr{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}


td {
  padding-left:0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: solid 1px black;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
  border-image: url(./borders/bottom.jpg);
}

td.spacer{
  padding-right: 20px;
}

td.roundleft{
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft:15px; /* Firefox top left corner */
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:15px; /* Firefox bottom left corner */
}

td.roundright{
  -moz-border-radius-topright:15px; /* Firefox top right corner */
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright:15px; /* Firefox bottom right corner */
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border-right: 2px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]As per my knowledge there is not way to add margin between two row, however you can get your desire result by adding div for your  and

I have done css and html for you find here

HTML Code: http://snipt.org/kyR3

CSS Code: http://snipt.org/kyP4

Change top-bottom padding for td to give more space between two row.

Here is the result....

Comment: The CSS works perfectly, but you just need a div within the td.

     `code` <td><div class='leftround'>Keanan</div></td>
     `code`

Comment: Your links are not responding.

Comment: @Code Lover:  Please would you place your code directly into your answer, your links are dead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good question on STackoverflow that tells how can we achieve the Cell Padding and Cell Spacing using CSS

Please See [Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-cellspacing-in-css)

Hope it solves your problem

Comment: The method that they describe there works, except for the fact that there is now also space between the <td>'s, which displays the green background between every white table cell.

I'm looking to add space between the rows, while not putting spaces between the cells.