# NLS missing message: Obsolete_attribute_name___ERROR_ in:

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse, nls

From some bitter, bitter experience I am on a mission to get my MyEclipse "warnings" to 0.

One is

```
NLS missing message: Obsolete_attribute_name___ERROR_ in: org.eclipse.wst.html.core.internal.HTMLCorePluginResources    deleteAuthorities.jsp   /C030/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/manageauthoritiess  line 16 JSP Problem
```

The offending point is the cellpadding in the line

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="viewTable">
```

I can guess what this means, but, again from bitter experience, that is not a good idea.

What does the message mean, and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get this error if you are using HTML5 since Cell spacing and Cell padding are obsolete in HTML5

You can try this below alternate solution to acheive the same effect

[Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-cellspacing-in-css)