# Eliminating space between table data

Tags: php, css, html-table

I am trying to get rid of the border space between the cells.  I thought cellspacing would do the trick but there is still a slim white border.  Can anyone give me some advice...

```
<body>
<center><table style="cellspacing:0; width:400px; border:none;">
<?
echo "<tr><td> Team </td><td>Correct Picks</td><td>Points</td></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($memberslist)) {
    if ($row['User_ID'] == $id) {
        echo "<tr bgcolor=\"gray\"><td>" . $row['User_ID'] . "</td><td><b>" . $row['Correct_Picks'] . " </b> /" . $maxcorrectpicks . "</td><td>" . $row['Points'] . "</td></tr>";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['User_ID'] . "</td><td><b>" . $row['Correct_Picks'] . " </b> /" . $maxcorrectpicks . "</td><td>" . $row['Points'] . "</td></tr>";
}
}
?>
</table></center>

</body>
```

Comment: `td {border: none;}` in your CSS. By the way, `<center>` is deprecated, and you should be using CSS instead of `bgcolor`

Comment: Post the generated HTML.

Comment: I tried the border:none but it didn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set cellpadding & cellspacing in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-cellspacing-in-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cellspacing=0;
```

is no CSS. That was once a HTML attribute:

```
<table cellspacing="0" style="width:400px">
```

See as well the related (duplicate?) question:

- [How to set cellpadding & cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-cellspacing-in-css)