# Controlling Spacing Between Table Cells

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to create a table where each cell has a background color with white space between them. But I seem to be having trouble doing this.

I tried setting `td` margins but it seems to have no effect.

```css
table.myclass td {
    background-color: lime;
    margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}
```

If I do the same thing with `padding`, it works, but then I don't have the spacing between cells.

Could someone help me with this?

```css
table.test td {
  background-color: lime;
  margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  /*padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;*/
}
```

```html
<table class="test">
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use the [`border-spacing`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border-spacing) property on the `table` element to set the spacing between cells.

Make sure [`border-collapse`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border-collapse) is set to `separate` (or there will be a single border between each cell instead of a separate border around each one that can have spacing between them).

Answer (score 34):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7JufT/8/).  You are going to need to take a look at using border-collapse and border-spacing.  There are some quirks for IE (as usual).  This is based on [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8381051/2106) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css).

```css
table.test td {
  background-color: lime;
  margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

table.test {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  *border-collapse: expression('separate', cellSpacing='10px');
}
```

```html
<table class="test">
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, that seems right. But could you describe the line `*border-collapse: expression('separate', cellSpacing = '10px');` a little for me?

Comment: Invalid CSS property name (so only parsed by broken parsers), followed by embedded JavaScript to set the (obsolete) cellspacing attribute to an invalid value (it should be 10 not 10px) in ancient versions of Internet Explorer. It isn't worth the effort for a cosmetic change in a dead browser.

Comment: They were used in earlier versions of IE apparently.  I had never used them, but according to the answer that I got this from, "expression('separate', cellSpacing = '10px') returns 'separate' but both statements are run, as in Javascript you can pass more arguments than expected and all of them will be evaluated."  I think that if you need to support the low-end IE browsers, Javascript might be a lot faster than this expression as the expressions are evaluated quite often (http://blog.dynatrace.com/2010/02/16/the-real-performance-overhead-of-css-expressions/).

Comment: You had me excited for a second about being able to use margin with table cells. However, it doesn't work - changing the `margin` values in the fiddle has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

```
table.test td {
    background-color: lime;
    padding: 12px;
    border:2px solid #fff;border-collapse:separate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use border-collapse and border-spacing to get spaces between the table cells. I would not recommend using floating cells as suggested by QQping.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fTMmv/1/)

Comment: Simplest solution so far. Given some of the other responses, I probably should check with different browsers.

Answer (score 2):

To get the job done, use

```
<table cellspacing=12>
```

If you’d rather “be right” than get things done, you can instead use the CSS property `border-spacing`, which is supported by some browsers.

Comment: No longer 'some', but 'most': IE7 is dying a quick death at the hands of IE8, which DOES support the `border-spacing` CSS property, so I personally do not feel the need to support IE7 any more (http://www.netmarketshare.com/report.aspx?qprid=3&qpaf=&qpcustom=Microsoft+Internet+Explorer+7.0&qpcustomb=0)