# where to enter "&nbsp" in the following code?

Tags: php

Can some one kindly help me find a place to add &nbsp between each of the rows in the echo statement. where and how can I add blank space between each row? kindly ignore the first set of echo statements that have been commented out. Thank you...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="docfullcss.css">

<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $dbname = 'employee_info';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    if(! $conn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    } 

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `docfull` ORDER BY `COL 7` ASC';    
    $retval = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        /*    (ignore this commented section)
              echo "<table>";
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>COL 1</td>";
              echo "<td>COL 2</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
              echo "</table>";
        */    
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['COL 1'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['COL 2'] . "</td>
                  </tr>" . $row['COL 3'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['COL 4'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['COL 5'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['COL 6'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['COL 7'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['COL 8'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['COL 9'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['COL 10'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['COL 11'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['COL 12'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['COL 13'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['COL 14'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['COL 15'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['COL 16'] . "</td><td>";
        echo "<br><br>";         
    }  

    mysqli_close($conn); 
?>
```

Comment: There is no need of &nbsp between tr, They automatically adjust themselves.

Comment: How you do add table row after closing the table?

Comment: use <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" > for automatically spacing between TR and TD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585461/controlling-spacing-between-table-cells)

Comment: you should consider usage of a template engine to avoid such messy code...

Comment: I guess your goal is to have margins between the rows? So you can do this by adding e.g. a `margin-top: 1em` to each `tr` in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['COL 1'] . "</td><td>" . $row['COL 2'] .     
"</td></tr>" . $row['COL 3'] .
```

You end row after `COL 2` and never start again till another iteration. You need to remove this `</tr>` after `COL 2` and add `<td>` to this place and add `</tr>` after `. $row['COL 16'] . "</td><td>";` , also you don'd need last `td` and those `<br>` tags on next line.

To have simple table you need something like this:

```
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {        
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['COL 1'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['COL 2'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['COL 3'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['COL 4'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['COL 5'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['COL 6'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['COL 7'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['COL 8'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['COL 9'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['COL 10'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['COL 11'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['COL 12'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['COL 13'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['COL 14'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['COL 15'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['COL 16'] . "</td></tr>";
}  
echo '</table>';
```