# Internet Explorer 8 & 9 add offset or margin to a div with the style display:table-cell

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer

I have a unique and extremely lame issue with IE and the style `display:table-cell.` I want to  center an image inside of a div and I found the easiest and quickest way is to use a table or display:table-cell;. It works in every major browser but the catch is IE 8 & 9 will offset the div with this style.

[image: IE Example]

The blue outline shows the boundaries of the div with the following CSS

```
 .user-photo div { height:200px; width:200px; display:table-cell; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;}
```

The parent containing div has this CSS

```
.user-photo { height:200px; width:200px; border:2px solid black; }
```

As far as I can tell, this may be an issue with the fact that I'm using ASP.NET tags with my regular HTML. I've tested this with html only and the child div stays inside of its boundaries.

Here is the code for the .ascx control shown in the image above.

```
<div id="picture-edit-div" class="p20">
    <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMsg" runat="server" Text="" Visible="False" />

    <div class="left user-photo">
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="plcImage" Visible="True">
            <div id="<%= plcImageID %>" ><cms:UserPicture ID="picUser" runat="server" Visible="true" /></div>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="plcImageActions" Visible="false">
            <div id="<%= placeholderID %>"  class="f12">PROFILE PHOTO</div>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>


    <div class="right user-edit-photo">
        <span class="container-upload"><cms:CMSFileUpload runat="server" CssClass="UploaderInputFile" ID="uplFilePicture" size="14" /></span>
        <asp:Button ID="btnClearUpload" runat="server" Text="CLEAR" UseSubmitBehavior="False" CssClass="right" />
        <p class="mt16 f12">Uploaded files must be under 5MB and one of the following file formats: jpeg, png, bmp.</p>
        <p class="mt10 mb20 f12">Image will fit to 200x200 pixels</p>

        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="SAVE" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="DELETE PHOTO" UseSubmitBehavior="False" CssClass="ml10" />
    </div>

    <asp:HiddenField runat="Server" ID="hiddenAvatarGuid" />
    <asp:HiddenField runat="Server" ID="hiddenDeleteAvatar" />

</div>
```

This is how the control renders in firefox and similarly in other browsers.
[image: FF example]

I think this is a bug with offset in IE but I can't be sure. Any help with this this problem would greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Looking at the HTML>layout tab in developer tools for my HTML only solution, I found the problem is reflected in the offset property. Firefox doesn't have this property in its developer tools so I assume my ASP.NET markup is screwing with that property.

EDIT-2: I'm reaching here but it could be that IE 8/9 displays table cells with the default cellpadding and/or cellspacing which are properties of a table that can only be set in markup.

EDIT-3: Rendered html for the .ascx control

```
    <td class="user-mid">

<!--
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
function UpdateForm(){ ; } 

//]]>
</script>-->

<div id="picture-edit-div" class="p20">

    <div class="left user-photo" >

            <div id="ctl00_plcMain_plcZone_lt_zoneCenter_UserSettings_UserPhoto_plcImage"><img alt="Avatar" src="/CMSModules/Avatars/CMSPages/GetAvatar.aspx?avatarguid=909868d6-120a-4e47-bca8-c4ea13b514a0&amp;maxsidesize=0" /></div>


    </div>
    <div class="right user-edit-photo">
        <span class="container-upload"><input type="file" name="ctl00$plcMain$plcZone$lt$zoneCenter$UserSettings$UserPhoto$uplFilePicture" id="ctl00_plcMain_plcZone_lt_zoneCenter_UserSettings_UserPhoto_uplFilePicture" class="UploaderInputFile" size="14" /><label for="ctl00_plcMain_plcZone_lt_zoneCenter_UserSettings_UserPhoto_uplFilePicture" id="ctl00_plcMain_plcZone_lt_zoneCenter_UserSettings_UserPhoto_lblUpload_uplFilePicture" style="display:none;">Upload file</label></span>
        <input type="button" name="ctl00$plcMain$plcZone$lt$zoneCenter$UserSettings$UserPhoto$btnClearUpload" value="CLEAR" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$plcMain$plcZone$lt$zoneCenter$UserSettings$UserPhoto$btnClearUpload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="ctl00_plcMain_plcZone_lt_zoneCenter_UserSettings_UserPhoto_btnClearUpload" class="right" />
        <p class="mt16 f12">Uploaded files must be under 5MB and one of the following file formats: jpeg, png, bmp.</p>
        <p class="mt10 mb20 f12">Image will fit to 200x200 pixels</p>

        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$plcMain$plcZone$lt$zoneCenter$UserSettings$UserPhoto$btnSave" value="SAVE" id="ctl00_plcMain_plcZone_lt_zoneCenter_UserSettings_UserPhoto_btnSave" />
        <input type="button" name="ctl00$plcMain$plcZone$lt$zoneCenter$UserSettings$UserPhoto$btnDelete" value="DELETE PHOTO" onclick="return deleteAvatar(&#39;ctl00_plcMain_plcZone_lt_zoneCenter_UserSettings_UserPhoto_hiddenDeleteAvatar&#39;, &#39;ctl00_plcMain_plcZone_lt_zoneCenter_UserSettings_UserPhoto_hiddenAvatarGuid&#39;, &#39;ctl00_plcMain_plcZone_lt_zoneCenter_UserSettings_UserPhoto_plcImage&#39; );__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$plcMain$plcZone$lt$zoneCenter$UserSettings$UserPhoto$btnDelete&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="ctl00_plcMain_plcZone_lt_zoneCenter_UserSettings_UserPhoto_btnDelete" title="Delete" class="ml10" />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$plcMain$plcZone$lt$zoneCenter$UserSettings$UserPhoto$hiddenAvatarGuid" id="ctl00_plcMain_plcZone_lt_zoneCenter_UserSettings_UserPhoto_hiddenAvatarGuid" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$plcMain$plcZone$lt$zoneCenter$UserSettings$UserPhoto$hiddenDeleteAvatar" id="ctl00_plcMain_plcZone_lt_zoneCenter_UserSettings_UserPhoto_hiddenDeleteAvatar" />
</div>

        </td>
```

Comment: Can you create a simple http://jsfiddle.net example of the markup and styles applied?

Comment: Have you tried using the developer tools in IE 8/9 to inspect the elements and see what styles are applied? Also - do you use a reset CSS?

Comment: You state that if you do this with HTML only, it works, but if you use ASP.NET control, it doesn't work. To my mind, that says there's a problem with how the ASP.NET control is rendering the HTML, not a bug with IE8/9...

Comment: I got the image with the blue outline using the developer tools. In addition to the styles I set for the div's, there are the 0 padding,  0 margin and font rules inherited from the body. When I look at the HTML>layout tab in tools the offset is 24 and the containing div has an offset of 20. I will try to show you on jsfiddle but the markup is assembled with a master page, layout page, and a webpart that contains this .ascx control. It may be the server side markup that is causing this issue. So the client side markup might not help.

Comment: I think you are right Mike but I'm new to ASP.NET tags. I'm not sure what property could do something like this.

Comment: @Gecko, from your browser, View Source and copy the relevant HTML into your question. It may be that IE is seeing a lot of white space around your tags and thinking it needs to add some space... One thing you could try doing is deleting as much of the white space around your ASP tags as possible (try to make it one long line) and see if that helps.

Comment: As Mike notes, it would be helpful (perhaps essential) to see the rendered HTML.

Comment: @Mike I tried what you suggested by getting rid of any extra white but no luck. I'm going to test a table instead of a div with display:table -cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My theory in my second edit was correct. I replaced the div with display:table-cell with a table with no cellspacing and no cellpadding. It rendered perfectly. To confirm this theory I took out the attributes for 0 cellpadding and 0 cellspacing and rendered the table again. In both IE and firefox the table was offset by the default cellpadding and cellspacing.

IE 8/9 render display:table-cell with the default table attribute of cellspacing="2px". Since these are markup attributes they cannot be changed with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the following style elements to the containing div (.user-photo):

```
display: table-row;
border-spacing: 0;
border-collapse: collapse;
```

This should have an equal effect as the `cell-spacing` attribute of the `table` element.

I faced a similar issue and found my inspiration here: [Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css)