# JSF Trinidad tr:table css issue

Tags: html, css, trinidad

I'm using tr:table and I want to add spacing between the cells so they won't be close to each other

The html that generate from has attribute cellSpacing = 0

`<tr:table>` tag has not such attribute.

how can I do it ?

thank,

John.

Comment: What is Trinidad? Where is the rest of your markup, what is the exact issue?

Comment: Trinidad is JSF framework that adds some component to jsf.
In this case the component is table. The issue is that I have table with cells and i want the cell be seperated from each other right now they are with out any space

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [skin](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/skinning.html) to have custom styling.

> A skin in Trinidad is a global style sheet that affects the entire application. You can create one skin for the entire application and as long as you have the  tag on your page it will get picked up. Every component will automatically use the styling as described by the skin. Any changes to the skin will be picked up at runtime, no change to code is needed. Skins are based on the Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) specification.

In your skin CSS you can then have something like:

```
af|table::content {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Also see:

- [Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css)
- [Selectors for skinning Trinidad components](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/skin-selectors.html)