# HTML Table with No Space

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following CSS code:

```
    tr.uprightTr
    {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        height: 10px;
        border: none;
        border-spacing: 0px;
    }
    td.uprightTd
    {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        height: 10px;
        border: none;
        border-spacing: 0px;
    }
    table.uprightTbl
    {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        border: none;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0px;
    }
```

And the following HTML:

```
<table class="uprightTbl" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr class="uprightTr">
         <td class="uprightTd"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
...
```

No matter what I tried, it keeps some space between elements. Any ideas on what I can try or might be doing wrong?

P.S: I also checked out the element on Chrome, element reaches the related css lines successfully.

Comment: Rule of thumb when doing css add `* { margin:0; padding:0; font-size:12px}` to top of page to cancel out browser defaults. Should make things a little easier.

Comment: Are you sure this "space" isn't some whitespace in the source or because of your line-height?  Typically the desired line-height is bigger than your actual font-size (`font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.4em`) for better readability.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try to add a CSS rule for all elements such as:

```
.uprightTbl * {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

It may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but gbtimmon's "rule of thumb" gave me the all-around solution.

Answer (score 5):

Apply below styles:

```
border-spacing:0;
border-collapse:collapse;
```

This query is already present: [Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

Add the below css code:

```
input[type=checkbox] { margin:0 }
```

By default, the browser set some margin around.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Check for any display:inline-block... and change to display:block.  Inline-block adds 3-4px of space after the element...

If you are using any images make sure they are displayed as block.