# How do I display images in an array to not have any spaces between them?

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <html>
<head>
 <body>
  <div id="image content">
      <table>
       <tr>
        <td id="">
           <script type="text/javascript">

    var myArray = new Array();

         myArray[0]=  new Array("images/bcpot002_r1_c1.jpg");
         myArray[1] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r2_c1.jpg");
         myArray[2] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r3_c1.jpg");
         myArray[3] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r4_c1.jpg");
 
 
    var myArray1 = new Array(); 

        myArray1[0] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r1_c2.jpg");  
        myArray1[1] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r2_c2.jpg");    
        myArray1[2]=  new Array("images/bcpot002_r3_c2.jpg");
        myArray1[3] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r4_c2.jpg");


   
    var myArray2 = new  Array();

       myArray2[0] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r1_c3.jpg");
       myArray2[1] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r2_c3.jpg");
       myArray2[2] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r3_c3.jpg");
       myArray2[3] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r4_c3.jpg");
    

   var myArray3 = new  Array();

      myArray3[0] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r1_c4.jpg");
      myArray3[1] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r2_c4.jpg")
      myArray3[2] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r3_c4.jpg");
      myArray3[3] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r4_c4.jpg");

  var myArray4 = new Array();

      myArray4[0] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r1_c5.jpg");    
      myArray4[1] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r2_c5.jpg"); 
      myArray4[2] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r3_c5.jpg");
      myArray4[3] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r4_c5.jpg");

  for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
      document.write("<tr><td><img src ='" +myArray[i] + "'/></td>");
      document.write("<td><img src ='" + myArray1[i] + "'/></td>");
      document.write("<td><img src ='" + myArray2[i] + "'/></td>");
      document.write("<td><img src ='" + myArray3[i] + "'/></td>");
      document.write("<td><img src ='" + myArray4[i] + "'/></td></tr>");
} 



         </script>
       </td>
      </tr>
 </table>

    </div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

The images displayed within the array, but i need them to not have any spaces between them, so they make one image using the array.
I need to possibly add somewhere in the  JavaScript code Or css with the following, but i am not entirely sure where or how to make this adjustment:

NoSpace
padding:0;
margin:0;
border:none:

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you apply those settings to the table, table properties, and images?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Table with No Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709632/html-table-with-no-space)

Comment: Thanks for the help I did use the table in css format.