# Using a table to lay out a grid of squares with fixed spacing where the width of each square is a percentage of the screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm laying out a simple grid of squares where the width of each square is 50% of the screen width and there's a fixed amount of spacing between each square. I've found a very intuitive way to do this using tables and one line of JavaScript (here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PNu9G/)):

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"></td>
    <td width="50%"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"></td>
    <td width="50%"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('td').height($('td').width());
```

This seems like a sane, semantic use of tables, but I'm almost certain I would be ripped apart by my fellow programmers for using tables for anything but tabular textual data. Is there any valid reason *not* to use the approach outlined above?

Comment: If tables are semantic, use them. Period.

Comment: Tables are less flexible.  It's easier to go to a mobile friendly design (e.g. one 100% width when the screens smaller than a certain size), if you app allows.

Comment: I would replace the `width` attribute by CSS, and if a table isn't semantic, consider a `div{display:table}` istead.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Good call on the width attribute – that will save a lot of markup. I'll change that now...

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand you can totally revamp tables to use non-tabular layout as well. `<table>` is just a tag with some default CSS and associated semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your HTML is going to contain **tabular** data, I don't think it's a problem to use tables. If you're using a `table` just to design your layout, you should go with "normal" elements (`div`, `section`, `article` etc.).

But, what I do want to point out, is that you're using layout-styles inside your HTML - now that's wrong. You should place your design inside CSS, and keep your HTML clean. Example:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: seperate;
    border-spacing : 10px;
}
td {
    width:50%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('td').height($('td').width());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PNu9G/2/).

Comment: Saw that you just updated your question at the time I posted my answer ;) . For more info about `border-collapse` (and more `table-stuff`), check out this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css).

Comment: Haha - yeah I actually removed my update because you covered it all and more! Thanks.