# Html: Difference between cell spacing and cell padding

Tags: html, css, cellspacing, cellpadding

What is the difference between cell spacing and cell padding?

Comment: try difference between cell spacing and cell padding on google.com

Comment: cellspacing is the  space between the cell wall  and cell padding expand the  cell wall not give space

Comment: Easy to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/QWRM6/

Comment: Funny thing, this is now the highlighted answer on google. I needed to remind myself of the difference. I googled it. This was the highlighted answer on google, and it answered my question. So, why isn't it a valid question?

Comment: cellspacing : space between cells; cellpadding : space between the cell border and it's content. So try to think about cellspacing as "cell-spacing or space between cells". But cellpadding is "how much padding is added inside the cell to limit the space left for text inside". For a quick demo with HTML code, have a look at here http://www.digizol.com/2008/08/cellspacing-vs-cellpadding-table.html

Comment: Related post - [Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/339923/465053)

Answer (score 47):

This is the simple answer I can give.

[image]

Answer (score 34):

[image: cellspacing and cell padding]

---

### Cell padding

is used for formatting purpose
which is used to specify the space needed between the edges of the cells
and also in the cell contents.
The general format of specifying cell padding is as follows:

```
< table width="100" border="2" cellpadding="5">
```

The above adds 5 pixels of padding inside each cell .

### Cell Spacing:

Cell spacing is one also used f formatting but there is a major
difference between cell padding and cell spacing. It is as follows: Cell
padding is used to set extra space which is used to separate cell walls
from their contents. But in contrast cell spacing is used to set space
between cells.

Answer (score 2):

`Cellpadding` is the amount of space between the outer edges of the 
table cell and the content of the cell.

`Cellspacing` is the amount of space in between the individual **table cells**.

**More Details** **[**Link 1**](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_29.html)**

**[Link 2](http://www.htmlite.com/lite012b.php)**

**[Link 3](http://www.hitmill.com/html/tables/two_f.html)**

Answer (score 2):

CellSpacing as the name suggests it is the Space between the Adjacent cells and CellPadding on the other hand means the padding around the cell content.

Answer (score 0):

Cell spacing and margin is the space **between** cells.

Cell padding is space inside cells, between the cell border (even if invisible) and the cell content, such as text.

Comment: So is there any difference between `Cellspacing` and `margin` of cell.