# How to remove useless space from table html design

Tags: html, css

There is everything fine but i'm not able to remove useless space. How to remove it anybody can solve it

By the way i have given picture below which part i want to remove there is useless white space and some space around phone area.

[image]

```html
 <table style="width: 100%; border: 10px solid #bdbdbd; background: #fff; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #444;">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" valign="top" border="0px">
                <div id="masterEmailData">
                <table style="background:#e7e7e7; height:auto; width:100%; height:100vh;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><img src="{9}/Content/content/image/logo1.png" class="img-responsive" style=" padding:0px 5px; max-width:250px;" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p style="text-align: center; background:#074f8e; padding:12px; color:#fff; font-size: 18px; margin: 5px 0">Phone</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><img src="../Content/content/image/emailImg.png" style=" padding:0px 5px; max-width:250px;" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
                </div>
            </td>


        </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks You!

Comment: The best way - would be not to use a table design for anything other than tabular data. Your approach offers you no benefit and many many drawbacks. `border: 10px solid #bdbdbd` looks like you put the border there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are the properties `cellpadding` and `cellspacing`. Set them to `0` and the white space should be gone.
[Here is an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517632/html-difference-between-cell-spacing-and-cell-padding) what they actually do.

Comment: Thanks you, By the way i'm using table because it's email templete

Comment: Ah. Makes sense :)