# Add space between two columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an HTML table. I need to have spacing between the table columns, but not the table rows.

My table columns also have border around them:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">hello</td>
    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">world</td>
    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">how</td>
    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">are</td>
    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">you?</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">hello</td>
    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">world</td>
    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">how</td>
    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">are</td>
    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">you?</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Css**

```
table td{
   border : 1px solid black;
   border-spacing: 1em 0;
 }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5mN4/1667/)

Comment: Try reading a bit on cellpadding and cellspacings.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/15517632/1221731

Comment: Apply `border-style: double;` as demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/u5mN4/1668/

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError . It works but its very small space. Any idea how can i increase this space ?

Comment: If you require them any larger, and you can't make `border-spacing` work, then consider adding "empty" cells that fulfill this role, you can then adjust the widths of these empty intermittent cells accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I use the cellspacing css property it does it between both rows and columns.

There is no cellspacing CSS property.

The property is called [`border-spacing`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#separated-borders) and …

> The lengths specify the distance that separates adjoining cell borders. If one length is specified, it gives both the horizontal and vertical spacing. If two are specified, the first gives the horizontal spacing and the second the vertical spacing. Lengths may not be negative.

… takes two values.

So:

```
border-spacing: 1em 0;
```

Comment: nah, border-spacing is also not working. You can check fiddle i updated fiddle with border-spacing

Comment: @Ancient — Take `border-collapse: collapse` out of your stylesheet. It causes `border-spacing` to be ignored. (And put an [mcve] in your question, don't hide vital parts of your code on a third party site).

Comment: i didn't added `border-collapse: collapse`. and yes i will add the css here also

Comment: Don't know about that .... maybe i tried to add previously but i am unable to see this collapse property in my style section. That's why i made statement. Anyway its working and thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
table {

    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 1em 0;

}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp

Answer (score 0):

Set `display` to `inline-table` and create right margin for each `td`:

```
table tr td{
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-table;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

You can remove the margin from last child this way:

```
table tr td:last-child {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/kisowoyaju/1/edit?html,css,output — That stops the columns lining up