# Creating text node and adding CSS

Tags: javascript, html, text

I'm attempting to create a text element and then add CSS attributes

I've tried to use the code below

```js
function create(text){
  var t = document.createTextNode(text);  
  t.style.color = "black"
  t.style.backgroundColor="white"
  t.style.borderRadius="20px"
  t.style.border="4px solid black"
  document.body.appendChild(t);
}
create("hello");
```

I expect to create a text with a white background and 20px border radius with a 4px solid black border

Comment: A textnode has no style, it's just text.  You might want to use some form of container, maybe a `<span>`, or `<div>` depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a text node, which I don't think you can add styles to, just use a `span` instead

```js
function create(text){
  var t = document.createElement("span");
  t.innerText = text;  
  t.style.color = "black"
  t.style.backgroundColor="white"
  t.style.borderRadius="20px"
  t.style.border="4px solid black"
  document.body.appendChild(t);
}
create("hello");
```

Comment: @Squill.is.me first of all, see this SO q/a on border padding and spacing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517632/html-difference-between-cell-spacing-and-cell-padding. Second, I'd recommend you check out the w3 tutorial on border-radius: https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: Last question, I swear: How do l edit the top element of the span using JS

Comment: @Squill.is.me I don't understand your question: What is the "top" element? Do you mean the parent element?

Comment: the distance the element is from the top of the document

Comment: @Squill.is.me just like any html element (with only position:static children): `elem.childNodes[0];` (you need to check that elem.childNodes[0] exists.) if you mean parent nodes, again a span, just like any html element, can only have one parent node

Answer (score 1):

You are having trouble because text nodes are not meant to be styled.

You should create a DOM element instead. I took your code and update it in order to create a `<p>` (the nearest element of text node I guess) with your CSS:

```js
function create(text) {
  var t = document.createElement('p');  
  
  t.innerText = text;
  
  t.style.color = "black"
  t.style.backgroundColor="white"
  t.style.borderRadius="20px"
  t.style.border="4px solid black"
  
  document.body.appendChild(t);
}

create("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right direction. The only thing you need to do is change `document.createTextNode(text)` with:

```js
var t = document.createElement('span');
t.innerText = text;
\\...
document.body.appendChild(t);
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is that you can only style HTML tags, and the the text node you created only contains the string you added, without a surrounding tag.

For example:

```html
<span>
  hello
</span>
```

is a tag with some text with it, while the `hello` text in the middle is a TextNode.

Hope this makes sense.

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode