# Extra white space on table cells

Tags: html, css, html-table, space

[image]

I am creating a table with 5 images across, one in each cell.
I want it to span 920px, with 10px gap between each cell.
Which equals 176 for each cell, so I made my images 176px wide.

This is my html and CSS:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><a class="fancybox-effects-c" rel="group" href="images/newhomes_02.jpeg" title="New Home Number Two"><img src="images/thumb_newhomes_01.gif" class="fade" alt="" /></a></td>
        <td><a class="fancybox-effects-c" rel="group" href="images/newhomes_02.jpeg" title="New Home Number Two"><img src="images/thumb_newhomes_01.gif" class="fade" alt="" /></a></td>
        <td><a class="fancybox-effects-c" rel="group" href="images/newhomes_01.jpeg" title="New Home Number Three"><img src="images/thumb_newhomes_01.gif" class="fade" alt="" /></a></td>
        <td><a class="fancybox-effects-c" rel="group" href="images/newhomes_02.jpeg" title="New Home Number Four"><img src="images/thumb_newhomes_01.gif" class="fade" alt="" /></a></td>
        <td><a class="fancybox-effects-c" rel="group" href="images/newhomes_01.jpeg" title="New Home Number Five"><img src="images/thumb_newhomes_01.gif" class="fade" alt="" /></a></td>
</table>



table {
    width:100%;
    cell-padding:"0";
    cell-spacing:"0";
    margin:0;
    border:none;
}

td {
    width:176px;
}
```

You can see in my attached image. that there is this white space on right side inside each cell.
I thought cell-padding and cell-spacing would fix it, but it didn't. Even doing td a set witdth of 176px didn't work. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the values for padding, margin and border explicitly. Take a look at the corrected code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      table {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }

      td {
        width: 176px;
        padding: 0 10px 0 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
      }
      td.last {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="imageContainer" style="width: 920px; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a class="fancybox-effects-c" rel="group" href="#" title="New Home Number Two"
              ><img src="testImage176.jpg" class="fade" alt=""
            /></a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a class="fancybox-effects-c" rel="group" href="#" title="New Home Number Two"
              ><img src="testImage176.jpg" class="fade" alt=""
            /></a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a class="fancybox-effects-c" rel="group" href="#" title="New Home Number Three"
              ><img src="testImage176.jpg" class="fade" alt=""
            /></a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a class="fancybox-effects-c" rel="group" href="#" title="New Home Number Four"
              ><img src="testImage176.jpg" class="fade" alt=""
            /></a>
          </td>
          <td class="last">
            <a class="fancybox-effects-c" rel="group" href="#" title="New Home Number Five"
              ><img src="testImage176.jpg" class="fade" alt=""
            /></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So why does this work - Ticked as the answer, no explanation as to why?

Comment: @Ricky: Because the table cells (td) are explicitely assigned padding, margin and border.

Comment: I'm aware, it was more of a prod for you to update your answer to explain this, rather than just doing someone elses job for them, albeit discretely

Answer (score 6):

You need `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` in table tag

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/psh4u/)**

Comment: Cheers buddy!

Another questions to solve my problem of evenly spacing the images.
There is still an extra few pixels on the far right img. I think its because i need img 4 and img 5 to be aligning right. Then perhaps the middle img (img3) to be aligning center.

Does that make sense? Is there an easy way to fix this? Sorry!!!

Comment: @AdamG I am not able to see the spaces between images coz we dont have image link or width of the image. Provide either image link or dimension

Comment: Just to note, both `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` are obsolete in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html).

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/85jzezwdf/ - <-- here is image. the light grey are images. the dark grey is the table background.

Answer (score 1):

`cell-spacing` and `cell-padding` don't exist in CSS.

For what you're trying to achieve, you can use:

```
border-spacing: 10px;
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Town/7Gkxr/

and

```
padding: 0 // applied to your td elements, gives you the equivalent of cellpadding="0"
```

There's an existing question on SO about this: [Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css)

Also, as your table contains images, I'd remove the width settings for `table` and `td`, as the table will be as wide as the sum of the images anyway.

Comment: Yeah but i need spacing between my images. I want the left image to be right against the left wall. and the right image right againgst the right wall. With 10x spacing inbetween every img

Comment: Ah, apologies - I've updated it to use [`border-spacing`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/border-spacing) instead.