# why doesn't table cellspacing work?

Tags: html, css, css-tables, cellpadding, cellspacing

I have tried every bit of tricks to make `cellspacing:0; cellpadding:0;` described in a css file to work but somehow the table doesn't accept this property but accepts while described inline as `<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">`. That's painstaking.

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer [How to set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css)

```
table { 
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML attribute `cellpadding=0` corresponds to setting `padding: 0` on all cells (`th` and `td` elements) of the table.

The HTML attribute `cellspacing` generally corresponds to setting `border-spacing` on the table, but in the common special case `cellspacing=0`, you get much better browser coverage by setting `border-collapse: collapse` on the table. It makes adjacent borders collapse but also removes spacing between cells.

HTML attributes sometimes map to CSS properties, but in general, they are two different worlds, and the mapping is complicated (see partial [description](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html2css.html) of the correspondence). In particular, CSS does not have properties like `cellspacing` and `cellpadding`.