# How to replace table attributes?

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation

Well I have the following HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
```

So I validated my HTML document and I found that these are obsolete. But if I remove them my website alignment won't work as I want. I need a good enough way to replace the attrbutes with CSS code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css)

Comment: why dont you just add width to the table itself? For Instance, `<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">`?

Comment: @NathanLee , he is looking to take it OUT of the table markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .table1_style
        {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0px;
        }
        .table2_style
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

<table class="table1_style">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="table2_style">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write in css this things:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0px;
width: 100%;
```