# Strange break appearing in Web page when viewed with Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

I have a Web page, http://www.chiaramail.com/intro.html, that displays fine in Chrome, IE and Safari, but when viewed with Firefox, the colored areas are split by a horizontal white line. I suspect this is whitespace that has something to do with the way I'm using tables, but I don't see what it is that Firefox doesn't like.

Here is the relevant HTML of the page:

```
              <table class="content" Rules="none" FRAME=void>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="background-color: #97BBDD"></td>
                          <td><b style="color:green"><center>Ensure the privacy of your mail.</center></b></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="background-color: #97BBDD"></td>
                          <td class="content content-data">Using <a href="technology.html">Envelope-Content Splitting</a><sup><font size="1">&#153;</font></sup> (ECS) technology, your e-mail becomes unreadable by everyone except your intended recipients. <a href="learn_more_privacy.html">Learn more</a>...</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td class="content-data" align="center"><b style="color:green"><center>Keep control of every message you send. Forever.</center></b></td>
                          <td style="background-color: #BBDD97"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td class="content content-data">Change your message at any time after you sent it. Delete it. Even make it disappear seconds after your recipients have read it. <a href="learn_more_edit.html">Learn more</a>...</td>
                          <td style="background-color: #BBDD97"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="background-color: #DD97BB"></td>
                          <td><b style="color:green"><center>Protect your recipients from spoofing and phishing.</center></b></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="background-color: #DD97BB"></td>
                          <td class="content content-data">ECS mail makes it virtually impossible for a sender to masquerade as you, due to the authentication scheme used by the ChiaraMail content server. <a href="learn_more_protect.html">Learn more</a>...</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td class="content-data" align="center"><b style="color:green"><center>Send really big attachments more efficiently.</center></b></td>
                          <td style="background-color: #97DDBB"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td class="content content-data">ECS technology gives you the ability to send attachments of almost unlimited size, without maxing out your recipients' inboxes. <a href="learn_more_lg_attachments.html">Learn more</a>...</td>
                          <td style="background-color: #97DDBB"></td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
    p {margin: 1em; }
    a.header { text-decoration:none; }
    a.footer { text-decoration:underline; }
    table.header { border: none; }
    table.footer { border: none; width:60%; }
    table.content { border: none; width:60%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
    td.header-img { border: none; }
    td.header { padding:10px; background-color: #808080; }
    td.footer { padding:10px; background-color: #f2f2f2; }
    td.content { padding:10px; text-align: left; }
    td.header:hover { background-color: #94B9DC; }
    td.footer:hover { background-color: #f2f2f2; }
    td.content-img:hover { background-color: #97BBDD; }
    td.content-data:hover { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
    #download_button:hover { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your `table.content` rules, add `border-collapse: collapse;`.

Answer (score 2):

```
table { 
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

See this post : [Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css)