# Table cell's spacing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply `background-color` to a table-cells. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DKNyf/)

```
<table>
<tr>
            <td>
                text
            </td>
            <td>
                text
            </td>
            <td>
                text
            </td>
</tr>
</table>


td{
    background-color: rgb(172,0,20);
}
```

How can I remove spacing between the table cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `border-collapse` property for the table:

CSS

```
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
   background-color: rgb(172,0,20);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DKNyf/1/

Answer (score 0):

try using like this

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
<tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The space between cells is called cellspacing and can be assigned in the html by using:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
<tr>
            <td>
                text
            </td>
            <td>
                text
            </td>
            <td>
                text
            </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellspacing.asp

You can also do this through CSS, see: [Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DKNyf/2/)**

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse