# Override table-specific attributes with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is it possible to override the table-specific attributes/values shown below (`border`, `cellpadding`, `cellspacing`) with CSS? I can't get to the HTML here to remove those attributes/values, so an external CSS file is all I have to work with!

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
```

Comment: P.S. I know I could use jQuery to remove the attributes, but I'm holding out for a cleaner, CSS-only solution.

Comment: Can't you just use `table{your changes here }` in your css?

Comment: The answer was previously mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css

Comment: Unless I'm not targeting the `<table>` correctly, my CSS can't override those inline attributes.

Comment: If you want a 'clean' approach, the best way is to have the back-end not produce the attribute mark-up you're trying to override. Though, given that the "*CSS...is all [you] have to work with*" it seems that advice is either too late, or of very limited use.

Comment: Okay. I'm an idiot. I pointed the style overrides at the `<td>`s instead of the `<table>` and all is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
table{
 border:0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
 padding:0;
}
```

Comment: See my comment above. Basically, you're right. I pointed my styles at the `<td>`s instead of directly at the `<table>` and all seemed to work. Ugh. Thanks.