# Want to use cellpadding and cellspacing in table by CSS class in different style file

Tags: html, css, html-table

Currently I am doing it by HTML and want to do same by CSS. I have tried myself but it not working. My working HTML is below.

```
<table class="product_tabel" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3">
```

But I am want to use it by CSS class `product_tabel` so how can I do this?

```
 .product_tabel
    {
    cellspacing :2;
    cellpadding:3;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css)

Comment: i am new on css and want to use by css file. and now i have checked that answer also. but that have td class not like css class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to this way

used to for `cellspacing`   `table{border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 3px;}` **and** `cellpadding`  `td{padding:2px;}`

**demo**

```css
 .product_tabel
    {
        border: solid 1px red;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 3px;
      border:solid 1px red;
    }

.product_tabel td, .product_tabel th{border:solid 1px green;padding:2px;}
```

```html
<table class="product_tabel">
<tr><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td><td>Hello</td></tr>
  </table>
```

```
table { border-spacing: 3px; } /* cellspacing */

th, td { padding: 3px; } /* cellpadding */
```

**[CSS Cellpadding](http://www.quackit.com/css/css_cellpadding.cfm)**

---

**[CSS Cellspacing](http://www.quackit.com/css/css_cellspacing.cfm)**

Answer (score 2):

You can provide css like:

```
.product_tabel { 
      border-spacing: 5px;
      border-collapse: separate; 
 } /* cellspacing */

.product_tabel th, .product_tabel td { padding: 5px; } /* cellpadding */
```

Answer (score 0):

use simply padding instead of cellpadding

```
.product_tabel
{
  padding:3px;
}
td{ padding:5px;}
```