# Two inline-blocks with text automatically break line

Tags: html, css

I have two divs with inline-block style, that both contains text with different font-sizes. They should be on the same line and then the second should break, but they are only if the second div is shorter then the body's width.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30gdLtce/2/)

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
}
#a {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
#b {
  /* No new line at b!! */
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">Fruits:</div>
<div id="b">Banana (3), Apple (2), Kiwi (5), Orange (1), Pear (11)</div>
```

Here I illustrate the problem:

What it **looks** like:

```
Fruits:
Banana (3), Apple (2), Kiwi (5), Orange (1), Pear (11)
```

What it **should** look like:

```
Fruits:  Banana (3), Apple (2), Kiwi (5),
         Orange (1), Pear (11)
```

And again, one more example of what it **shouldn't** look like, but could if the div was inline:

```
Fruits:  Banana (3), Apple (2), Kiwi (5),
Orange (1), Pear (11)
```

Is there anyway I can fix this?

I have tried using white-space: nowrap and word-wrap: break-word, but none of them seems to work.

Comment: Did you see my updated answer? Could you comment anything?

Comment: @SergeyDenisov Yes it's just what I needed and solved the problem.

Comment: Could you upvote and accept then?

Comment: @SergeyDenisov Yes I will, thanks for the brilliant answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `display: table-cell` for it, but then you should use `padding` instead `margin`, because:

> [Margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) applies to all elements, except elements with table [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) types other than `table-caption`, `table` and `inline-table`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/2q8710vw/1/)

```css
div {
  display: table-cell;
  font-family: Arial;
}
#a {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
#b {
  /* No new line at b!! */
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">Fruits:</div>
<div id="b">Banana (3), Apple (2), Kiwi (5), Orange (1), Pear (11)</div>
```

Comment: Wait.. Found something.. the margin-right on #a doesn't work :/

Comment: @Murplyx Margins do not work on table cells. You can try `padding` or `border-spacing`. See [Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/339923/1529630)

Comment: @Murplyx yes, as @Oriol said, you should use `padding` then. Improved my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `inline-block`s, you can

1. Float the first item to the left.
2. Make the second one establish a block formatting context (BFC) in order to prevent it from overlapping the former. A common way to establish BFCs is `overflow: hidden`.

```css
div {
  font-family: Arial;
}
#a {
  float: left; /* Push to the left */
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
#b {
  overflow: hidden; /* Establish BFC */
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">Fruits:</div>
<div id="b">Banana (3), Apple (2), Kiwi (5), Orange (1), Pear (11)</div>
```