# Cells table spacing with CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm really new with `HTML/CSS` but I need to use both langages in order to realize my Django web application.

I get a problem with my `<table>` because the cells spacing doesn't take account from my css file.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #0083A2;
}
.nav navbar-brand {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.active {
  background-color: #454545;
}
h1,
h2,
h4 {
  color: #0083A2;
}
.button {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
.form-fields {
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.col-sm-6 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  list-style: None;
}
.col-sm-8 {
  list-style: initial;
}
.col-sm-10 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 800%;
  list-style: None;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #0083A2;
  color: #454545;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <h4><b><font color="#0083A2"> Récapitulatif des 3 dernières fiches individuelles créées: </b></font></h4>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Civilité</th>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Prénom</th>
        <th>Date de Naissance</th>
        <th>Ville de Naissance</th>
        <th>Pays de Naissance</th>
      </tr>
      {% for item in identity %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.lastname }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.firstname }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.birthday }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.birthcity }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.birthcountry }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I wrote something wrong in my two scripts ? If you have advices, I will take account with pleasure !

Thank you !

**EDIT :**

This is my table :

[image]
But none answers make a space between cells ..

Comment: The spacing is working with the code in your question.

Comment: @falguni — What makes you think the OP is trying to **remove** the spacing? They've explicitly set it to a large number.

Comment: @falguni Doesn't work .. `border-spacing` and `border-collapse` have no effect on my html page

Comment: @Quentin Spacing are working, but you forgot `{% for item in identity %}` between `</tr>` and `<tr>`. The problem comes from there ?

Comment: — That's template code which won't appear in the final DOM. Adding it to the HTML (instead of to a template language which gets converted into HTML) makes the HTML invalid.

Comment: @falguni — They're already doing that (which is why the code in the question works)

Comment: @Quentin It's for Django application. With Django, it works like that : mix pythonic variables with HTML

Comment: — Yes, but the live demo embedded in the question **isn't** a Django application, so the template won't be processed, and what you type is what will be sent to the browser.

Comment: I don't know why exactly, but it doesn't work. Even if I remove pythonic variable inside my html code. I need to use HTML template to generate view in my Django application, and for the moment I can't. I don't get table cells spacing as I want.

Comment: We can't tell why it doesn't work either. You haven't shown us the problem. You need a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This question might be also solved by this: [Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css)

I would like to suggest to read more about `table` and what you can do from css and specificly what you cannot do.

In this case you can change the cellpadding or cellspacing off a table from css by using other similar properties.
You can manipulate the padding of the cells which is an equivalent of cellpadding and border-spacing for cellspacing.

I suggest you read a bit more about it as you have a lot of css for the table elements that seems out of place (like list-style).

Good starting reference could be this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: "In this case you cannot change the cellpadding or cellspacing off a table from css" — Why not?

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution : write css directly inside my HTML code and it works !

Comment: @Valentin — Why did you accept this the answer which solved your problem? Your comment says that your solution is completely different to anything suggested here.

Comment: @Quentin Wait I'm writting the answer and my working script.

Comment: @Quentin check here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp
There is property to change the cellpadding or cellspacing. There are other equivalent properties in css to achieve the same result by using `margin` and `padding`.

Comment: @GeorgeAntonakos — "There is property to change the cellpadding or cellspacing." — Yes, and the code in the question is using one of the successfully.

Comment: @GeorgeAntonakos — "There are other equivalent properties in css to achieve the same result by using margin and padding." — No. While `padding` is used instead of `cellpadding`, it is `border-spacing` that replaces `cellspacing` … and which is used in the code in the question.

Comment: @Quentin you are correct about margin, I will edit my answer

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer thanks to @GeorgesAntonakos :

I have to write css conditions directly inside my HTML template :

```
<style>
table, th, tr {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
    <h4><b><font color="#0083A2"> Récapitulatif des 3 dernières fiches individuelles créées: </b></font></h4>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Civilité</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Prénom</th>
            <th>Date de Naissance</th>
            <th>Ville de Naissance</th>
            <th>Pays de Naissance</th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in identity %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.lastname }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.firstname }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.birthday }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.birthcity }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.birthcountry }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br></br>
    </div>
```

This solution works for me.

[image]

Comment: `border-collapse: collapse;` — This does the opposite of what the code in the question (which you said was being ignored) does. You've removed the spacing between the cells instead of setting it to 100px now.

Comment: I didn't mention anything regarding that in my answer. I adviced you to read more about tables and maybe use `padding` and `border-spacing` to achieve the spacing you need for your layout.

Comment: @GeorgeAntonakos Yeah and I found a correct solution from your link ^^

Answer (score -2):

use

```
!important;
```

in your css code more details :https://appendto.com/2016/04/css-important-rule-how-to-use-it-correctly/

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #0083A2;
}
.nav navbar-brand {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.active {
  background-color: #454545;
}
h1,
h2,
h4 {
  color: #0083A2;
}
.button {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
.form-fields {
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.col-sm-6 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  list-style: None;
}
.col-sm-8 {
  list-style: initial;
}
.col-sm-10 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 800%;
  list-style: None;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #0083A2;
  color: #454545;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <h4><b><font color="#0083A2"> Récapitulatif des 3 dernières fiches individuelles créées: </b></font></h4>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Civilité</th>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Prénom</th>
        <th>Date de Naissance</th>
        <th>Ville de Naissance</th>
        <th>Pays de Naissance</th>
      </tr>
      {% for item in identity %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.lastname }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.firstname }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.birthday }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.birthcity }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.birthcountry }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing too .. I don't know why, but all answers don't bring any effect on my table.

Comment: please give more details of your table and questions then we understand actually what is your requirement .