# Format HTML table to paste into Google Doc

Tags: html, css, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm generating HTML code for regular tables:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
       <td>Data</td>
       <td>Data</td>
       <td>Data</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

After generation, I open the HTML file in a browser (Firefox) and copy and paste into blank Google Doc, BUT Google Docs translates the table without borders borders and default format.

There is a way to format the HTML table to meed the Google Docs requirements?
Or there is a way to format a lot of tables of a Google Doc using a macro ?  (I mean table borders and single linespacing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing I notice is the `<table>` has `cellpadding="0"` declared on it, twice.

> “Do not use [`cellpadding` or `cellspacing`], as [they have] been deprecated. The  element should be styled using CSS.” —[MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

See this other StackOverflow question for how to [set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css).

This actually addresses your problem, as adding a `border-collapse` property to your `table` style will cause allow a table to paste into a Google Doc as a table… *if* you set it to `separate`.

*Or* if you add `padding` to your `td` (and `th` if you have them)

I should also note, different browsers will produce different results. I've also found how much is selected can effect how the table pastes in. My best advice is to experiment based on the look of your table and your desired result.

Comment: The link is dead =(

Comment: Ah, I think I might have created that doc on an account under an old employer, I can't find any trace of it.