# How do I edit HTML styles with CSS? Unknown property name

Tags: html, css

Example:

```
<table class="tborder" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
```

How would I edit the "cellspacing" value using only CSS?

Comment: Check out this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css