# How can we set only outer border to table in CKEDITOR

Tags: html, css

I am unable to add only outer body to HTML table in CKEDITOR. I have tried to remove inner border from advanced option in CKEDITOR but that is not working as well.

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td border="0">&nbsp;</td>
      <td border="0">&nbsp;</td>
      <td border="0">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you've set the border via HTML and that is the default behaviour. Better (in every case) set the border with CSS.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td border="0">&nbsp;</td>
      <td border="0">&nbsp;</td>
      <td border="0">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can also remove `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` by using some more CSS. For more informations see [Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css)

Answer (score -1):

Try this. I have added this css:

```
table td {
  border: 0;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```css
table td {
  border: 0;
}
table {
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td border="0">&nbsp;</td>
      <td border="0">&nbsp;</td>
      <td border="0">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```