# I need help finding out how to put a space between rows of a table in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have a table with many rows, and I just need to find a way to put a line of space in between each row.

```
  Example: a b c
 
           d e f
```

I'm still very new to HTML/CSS/JS, so I was hoping I could get a pretty simple explanation, as I've seen the question asked here but I was still unsure of how to replicate it. Here are my tables in HTML, and the code I used in JS. [image: Here's my table with some JS code.] [image: Here's my table in HTML.] If anyone could help me out with this, I'd really appreciate it!

I've tried to make a class for <tr> and using border-collapse, but to no avail, as I may have done something wrong. I've also tried messing around in the JS code, but I'm not sure if I should add the spaces in between from there or through the HTML.

Comment: Could you just use `<tr rowspan="2">`?

Comment: I just tried that, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: It really depends on how you want this to look exactly, here's example code for cell padding and spacing between rows: https://jsfiddle.net/ufgrz06s/ (also please don't post images of code, post actual code. ideally as [mre] using the `<>` button)

Comment: You can add a blank line like so: <tr><td colspan=10></td></tr>.  The value of colspan should be equal or greater than your number of column. Alternatively, you can apply padding to the table cell using css.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/set-cellpadding-and-cellspacing-in-css

Comment: I apologize for posting images, I should have read more into what I should do before posting questions. But thank you so much for the reply, that's pretty much what I wanted!

Comment: I am reviewer, please don't add images of code, paste it as text instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need a bigger space between to lines, for that you can use css.

```
.tableRow {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Another solution would be adding an empty `tr`, between the one that have content.

```
<tr style="height: 20px">
    <td></td> <td></td>
</tr>
```